# ExtJS - Getting ID of record that was just saved

Tags: javascript, asp.net, wcf, extjs

I need to save some data and return the ID that is created in the SQL 2005 database. I need the ID to pass to another object before saving that so I can associate them correctly.

What is the best way to accomplish this with Ext? Is there anything built into the Framework that makes this simple?

Thanks.

```
                function AddPromotionType() {
                var currentDate = new Date();
                var newTypeJsonObject = {
                    promotionTypeId: '0',
                    promotionType: Ext.getCmp('txtPromoType').getValue(),
                    updatedBy: userid, 
                    updateDate: currentDate
                }

                // serialize our service object
                var newLevelJsonData = Ext.encode(newTypeJsonObject);

                // call the web service and pass over our service object
                Ext.lib.Ajax.defaultPostHeader = 'application/json';
                Ext.Ajax.request({
                    url: 'Service/AddPromoType',
                    method: 'POST',
                    params: newLevelJsonData,
                    success: function(response, options) {
                        AddTypeWindow.destroy();
                        AddTypeWindow.hide();

                        // refresh dropdown to reflect new data

                        Ext.getCmp('newPromoType').getStore().reload();                        
                    },
                    // if data fails to save, show message
                    failure: function(response, options) {
                        Ext.MessageBox.alert('Error saving new promotion type', response.responseText);
                    }
                });
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your server is passing back the updated data with the new id the response param of your success callback should contain it.  When using the facilities built into Stores that automate Ajax calls (e.g., Ext Direct, REST API support, etc.) the id gets automatically updated on the appropriate Record for you and you can handle the store's `add` event to inspect the Record.  However, since you're doing a manual Ajax call it's up to you to inspect your response if you need the id immediately.

Comment: Agree this is server side not client side.

Comment: Great. Thanks for the clarification. I'll have to adjust the proc to pass back the record value and the C# as well.